# sortUsingComparator on NSDictionary in NSMutableArray with multiple objectKeys

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am trying to sort a mutableArray of NSDictionaries, currently I can do this by sorting with one objectForKey value, but the problem with this is that alot of these values can be the same so I need to have the other objectForKey to sort the array. I was wondering how, if the first objectForKey comparison returns an identical value, how I could then move onto a second objectForKey comparison and so on and so forth..

Currently I am doing this, which works.. but obviously only on the one key.

```
[dataArrayOfDictionaries sortUsingComparator:^ NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *d1, NSDictionary *d2)
    {
        NSString *n1 = [d1 objectForKey:@"DESCRIPTION"];
        NSString *n2 = [d2 objectForKey:@"DESCRIPTION"];
        return [n1 localizedCompare:n2];
    } ];
```

In my investigation I have tried this -

```
[dataArrayOfDictionaries sortUsingComparator:^ NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *d1, NSDictionary *d2)
{
    NSString *n1 = [d1 objectForKey:@"DESCRIPTION"];
    NSString *n2 = [d2 objectForKey:@"DESCRIPTION"];
    return [n1 localizedCompare:n2];
    n1 = [d1 objectForKey:@"ID"];
    n2 = [d2 objectForKey:@"ID"];
    return [n1 localizedCompare:n2];

} ];
```

However this is not working as it sorts on description then completely resorted based off ID, I am wanting it if Description keys are the same to then sort those values by the ID key.. if that doesn't work then go down the list of Keys until its sorted.. I hope this makes sense.. any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pretty much described the solution in your question: “if Description keys are the same to then sort those values by the ID key”.  You can translate that English sentence directly into code:

```
[dataArrayOfDictionaries sortUsingComparator:^ NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *d1, NSDictionary *d2) {
    NSString *n1 = [d1 objectForKey:@"DESCRIPTION"];
    NSString *n2 = [d2 objectForKey:@"DESCRIPTION"];
    NSComparisonResult result = [n1 localizedCompare:n2];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
        n1 = [d1 objectForKey:@"ID"];
        n2 = [d2 objectForKey:@"ID"];
        result = [n1 localizedCompare:n2];
    }
    return result;
}];
```

You could also perform the sort using two `NSSortDescriptor` objects:

```
[dataArrayOfDictionaries sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"DESCRIPTION" ascending:YES
        selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)],
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ID" ascending:YES
        selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)],
    nil]];
```

Comment: :P okay... I feel I know the logic but not the code.. I didnt know to call NSOrderedSame... I have seen that used in a similar question.. I should have tried that :(... i will try it out now :P

Thank you very much for the reply :)

Comment: would the second example you have given just continually change the array depending on the sortDescriptorWithKey.. i.e. sort for DESCRIPTION, then gets changed by sortDescriptorWithKey for ID so on and so forth... im going to give it ago.. then ill mark you! thanks for all the help.. the first example seems to work for me great... even though I am abit lost with the idea (what happens when a higher object key is not the same.. dose it later go on to sort by lower object key values? or are they left.. im trying to get the logic on that.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by “just continually change the array depending on the sortDescriptorWithKey”.  Both examples do the same thing: they compare two elements (dictionaries) based on the “DESCRIPTION” key's values.  They only look at the “ID” key's values if the ”DESCRIPTION” key's values are equal.

Comment: yup.. just tried it out and it works the same.. sorry for confusing you :P I was thinking it was going to do something else.. but as you say they both work the same.. in your opinion is the second solution faster? not having to deal with the if statements.. or any other particular reason. thanks very much for the help :P

Comment: I don't know which is faster. You should try both and time them if it's important.

Comment: :P okay I might try that :) not super important but if ones quicker (relating to better i guess) than the other I may as well use that one I guess.